# Equivalent of Archimedean Property

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am reading real analysis textbook by Stephen C. Lay on the Archimedean property of $\mathbb R$. One of the three equivalents is stated as follow:

> For each $x > 0$ and for each $y \in \mathbb R$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $nx > y$.

At least to my untrained novice eyes, it is counter intuitive. I can understand if $y$ is positive, but what happens when it is not? For example, when $x = 1$ and $y = -1$, since $0 \notin \mathbb N$?

I have searched this site for the answer under "Archimedean Property" but could not find one. I hope someone could give me intuition and perhaps some examples. Thank you for your time and helps.

Comment: Its trivial since all $n$ satisfy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x>0$ but $y\le0$, then *any* natural number $n\ge1$ satisfies $nx>y$, so it is a trivial case.

Comment: Thank you! I think I did not read the statement carefully enough.

Comment: I am so embarrassed - turns out the answer is so simple. Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 6):

If $x>0$ and $y\le 0$, then

$$\color{red}{1}\times x>0>-1>-2>-3...>y>...$$

so $n=\color{red}{1}$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I did not read the problem carefully enough.

Comment: I am so embarrassed - turns out the answer is so simple. Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 1):

Choose simply $$n=\lceil\frac{y}{x}\rceil+1$$
You will then have $$nx=\lceil\frac{y}{x}\rceil x+x>y$$
(since $x>0$)

Comment: Thank you for your alternative answer.